# Load knockout template from html file with webpack

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to load my knockout templates from external files.
My setup is as follows:

- npm
- webpack
- typescript

Now, I have tried a few different options but none worked:

## text-loader / raw-loader / html-loader

```
template: require("text-loader!./my-component.html")
// or
template: require("raw-loader!./my-component.html")
// or
template: require("html-loader!./my-component.html")
```

Didn't work as this returns a text that resembles Javascript code with my template somewhere inside.

## [knockout-template-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knockout-template-loader)

```
template: require("knockout-template-loader!html-loader!./my-component.html")
```

Didn't work as it just returns an empty object.

## [script-template-loader](https://github.com/grofit/script-template-loader)

```
template: require("script-template-loader?addToDom=true!./hello.html")
```

This has two problems:

1. template doesn't like HTMLScriptElement objects
2. The generated script has no actual content beside the string `[object Object]`

## `require` option

```
template: {require: "text-loader!./my-component.html"}
```

Didn't work as I am getting an error at runtime:

> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at `__webpack_require__`

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html-loader plugin is indeed working. Why it wasn't working at first was that I registered `knockout-template-loader` in my webpack.config.js as the default loader for html files.
Looks like it is using that even if a specific loader is specified in the require.
After removing that rule, it works now